# running time accuracy on a dual oct core when using only one thread

Tags: c++, performance, time, cplex

I have a set of instances for a combinatorial optimization problem. I want to use CPLEX software linked with C++ to solve each instance on a computer having the following properties given by `lscpu` command:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                16
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-15
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    8
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 62
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               3299.910
BogoMIPS:              6599.11
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              25600K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15
```

I capture the solution time of CPLEX using the following code:

```
clock_t tic , toc ;
tic = clock () ;
STATUS = cplex.solve() ;
toc = clock() - tic ;
TIME = ((float) toc )/CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
```

Since later I want to compare this solution time with another algorithm, I want to have rather stable results. So I used the following code to force CPLEX use one thread:

```
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Threads, 1);
```

I am wondering if forcing CPLEX to use exactly one thread can help obtain more stable results? The information given by `lscpu` command is for a Dell PowerEdge M620 blade server with dual oct core 3.33GHz Intel Xeon E5-2667 v2 processors and 256GB RAM running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6. It is possible that other people use the server while my job is running on it. My second question is about running other jobs each using exactly one thread. Do such jobs affect the execution time of each other?

Comment: Two hints about benchmarking: First of all use optimized code. Secondly, do it a *lot* of times. If you do it enough times, the differences between the runs will average out.

Comment: "Do such jobs affect the execution time of each other?" - of course they do. Multiple running jobs may be scheduled on different CPUs (and may bounce around between cores) which may cause latencies as the OS brings jobs from one CPU to another. You may also see cache effects - the CPU the program is woken up on may have a hot or cold cache of its data. More jobs running on the CPU may lead to thermal throttling which can impact your wall-clock runtime. And more..

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks Jesper. If the jobs each use a single thread and they run independently of each other, then why the OS schedules them? They can run in parallel each on a thread (given that the number of jobs is less than or equal to 16) and each thread is on a different core. Are there any hope to have more stable results even by setting a program to use one thread? More precisely, I expect a single threaded program show more stable results than a multithreaded one. Is that correct?

Comment: The OS will typically switch intensive threads between cores to balance the thermal load across a multicore processor. You might be able to lock your process to one core - look up processor affinity or similar. Also be aware of 'hyperthreading' where one core behaves like two virtual cores - this can have a detrimental effect on CPU-intensive stuff because you get more contention. Also, CPLEX has a 'deterministic' mode for parallel MIP that should make the CPLEX side repeatable even in parallel thread mode. I don't know if that would also benefit repeatability when running on one thread?